# pre/post-increment in conditional skipped by short-circuit evaluation

Tags: c#, compilation

So, if I have an expression like:

```
if (obj != null && i++ % divisor == 0)
{
....
}
```

and `obj` is `null`, then `i` is never incremented. If I use

```
i++; 
if (obj != null && i % divisor == 0)
{
....
}
```

instead, then, of course, `i` is incremented.

Is this by design? I understand short-circuit evaluation from an optimization point of view, but I had (incorrectly) assumed that the compiler would recognize the post-increment expression and evaluate it regardless.

(If this is in the spec, I couldn't find it - just looking for some (gasp) opinions here.)

**Update**

Here's the actual code.

```
    private int _frameNumber = 0;

    private void simulator_OnFrameEnd(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        _frameNumber++; 

        if (_visualizer != null && _frameNumber % _config.VisualizerUpdateFrequency == 0)
        {
            var field = _simulator.GetField(_config.PreviewField);

            _visualizer.Update(field, _simulator.FrameTime);
        }

        if (_frameNumber % _config.OptimizerRegridFrequency == 0)
        {
            _simulator.UpdateFieldGrids();

        }

    }
```

Comment: You can use `&` if you want that behaviour.

Comment: If you have to ask this question, then it's an indication that your code is not readable.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Care to elaborate?

Comment: Simple. Others will have the same question when reading your code. I suggest you structure your code so that this question does not arise.

Comment: You should show more context, is this in a loop? Is `i` the index and `obj` the object that you get at the index?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Okay, the three other guys I showed this to had no trouble reading it. Also, I appreciate the advice, however the question is about whether or not this is *correct* behavior on the part of the compiler, not the pros and cons of my coding style used within the SO message editor box.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Not in a loop. I'll update with the actual method from my test app.

Comment: Also, I'll be the first to admit that incrementing within the conditional in the above method, especially when the modified value is then used in second `if` within the same method, is crappy - I was just trying to find out if this was correct behavior. A LOT of tools have enable/disable options for short-circuit evaluation (and other optimizations). Also, "optimizations" should (imho) not change the output of an app. But, I'll survive.

Comment: Of course the behavior is correct. You are laboring under the misapprehension that the short circuiting behavior is an *optimization*. It is no such thing; it is an *important guarantee*. If it were an optional optimization then you could not guarantee that `if (obj != null && obj.ToString().Length > 10)` does not crash!

Comment: @JohnSaunders advice is good advice; this code is hard to read and bad style. If you don't understand what the meanings of the operators are in C# then (1) educate yourself, and (2) write code that is easier for people who don't understand what the meaning is to read and maintain.  A good rule of thumb is that *every expression should have exactly zero side effects* -- expressions should be useful for their *value*, not their *effect* -- and *every individual statement should cause exactly one side effect*. Statement with multiple side effects are hard to reason about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is most definitely by design. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states:

> The operation `x && y` corresponds to the operation `x & y` except
>   that if x is false, y is not evaluated, because the result of the AND
>   operation is false no matter what the value of y is. This is known as
>   "short-circuit" evaluation.

So, it doesn't matter what your statement is, whether it has a post-increment or not, it won't be evaluated if it's short-circuited.

Answer (score 6):

The post-increment is only post evaluation of the statement. Since the statement is never evaluated (it's short circuited) it's skipped.

A more visual way to think of it is to imagine the if statement as being nested:

```
if (obj != null)
{
   if (i++ % divisor == 0)
   {
   ...
   }
}
```

Here we see immediately that `i` will not be incremented. Similarly when an `if` statement is short circuited the behaviour is similar to the above and the post increment is not queued.

Comment: @DavidLively: It is precisely *because* the expression after it modifies state that it must *not* be executed! The whole point of the short circuiting operation is to *guard against the production of the side effects of the right hand side*.

Comment: @EricLippert i get that, and it certainly makes sense. My coffee/beer-stained copy of the dragon book, though, led me to a very different interpretation of the purpose and semantic implications of this construct. Again, I understand this is BAD style - the question was about the "correctness" of the generated code. (As an EE, having worked on a compiler team (Keil) in the past, I realize that this level of "bug" almost never happens in a mature tool. Thus, my confusion.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is by design. From the specification:

**7.12.1
Boolean conditional logical operators**

> The operation x && y is evaluated as `(bool)x ? (bool)y : false`. In
>   other words, x is first evaluated and converted to type bool . Then,
>   if x is true , y is evaluated and converted to type bool , and this
>   becomes the result of the operation. Otherwise, the result of the
>   operation is false

In your code, y is `i++ % divisor == 0` so `i++` will not be executed if `obj` is null.

Answer (score 2):

The frameNumber is not incremented because `_visualizer != null` returns false. So the code doesn't even bother to check/excecute the increment and modulo operation.

If you'd switch the checks around (ie `if (_frameNumber++ % 5 == 0 && _visualizer != null)`) then `_frameNumber` gets incremented... because the operaion actually is executed.

So yes: This is wanted behavior and it is by design.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's by design. The left side is never evaluated if the right side evaluates to `false`, including any side effects that might occur (such as the increment)

> The operation `x && y` corresponds to the operation `x & y`, except that `y` is evaluated only if `x` is `true`
>
> —source [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691310%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

<sup>Yes that's an older version of the documentation, but the language is clearer, IMO.</sup>

If you want the increment to be evaluated use this:

```
if (_visualizer != null & _frameNumber++ % _config.VisualizerUpdateFrequency == 0)
{
    ...
}
```

If you want to perform the increment even when `visualizer == null` but not the modulus:

```
var _prevFrameNumber = _frameNumber++;
if (_visualizer != null && _prevFrameNumber % _config.VisualizerUpdateFrequency == 0)
{
    ...
}
```